# RenderScript - arm64-v8a device can't load any generated ScriptC file, "libRSSupportIO.so" not found

Tags: android, renderscript

I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 in which I want to use a RenderScript library. Said library uses the Support version of RenderScript and has the line `RenderScript.forceCompat()` before `RenderScript.create()`.

The gradle file of the app also has these lines in the dependencies block:

`defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled true
    }`

The ABI splits contain the split for the arm64-v8a ABI.

The following stacktrace is produced when the library tries to initialize a ScriptC file:

`05-22 10:23:34.600 7568-7633/com.picmix.mobile V/RenderScript_jni: RS compat mode
05-22 10:23:34.608 7568-7633/com.picmix.mobile V/RenderScript_jni: Unable to load libRSSupportIO.so, USAGE_IO not supported
05-22 10:23:34.615 7568-7942/com.picmix.mobile E/RenderScript: Couldn't load libRSSupportIO.so
05-22 10:23:34.633 7568-7942/com.picmix.mobile E/RenderScript: Unable to open shared library (/data/app/com.picmix.mobile-1/lib/arm64/librs.img2alloc.so): dlopen failed: library "libRSSupportIO.so" not found
05-22 10:23:34.633 7568-7942/com.picmix.mobile E/RenderScript: Unable to open system shared library (/system/lib/librs.img2alloc.so): (null)`

Apparently this only happens in the S6 and S7 devices, both using the armv8l architecture. I tested this on other devices (Oppo A37, Huawei ALE-L21, and Samsung Galaxy J2), and it worked fine there - all of them are below API 23, and the Oppo and S6 have the "aarch64" architecture.

Am I missing something? Do I have to include `libRSSupportIO.so` manually? Because when I looked into the libs folder of my APK, I see `libRSSupport.so` in there.

EDIT: My build tools version is 25.0.3.

EDIT 2: If the following stacktrace is relevant, here's the SIGSEGV right after the app crashed.

`05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zerofltexx/zeroflte:7.0/NRD90M/G920FXXU5EQCK:user/release-keys'
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '11'
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm64'
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: pid: 19971, tid: 21568, name: AsyncTask #6  >>> com.picmix.mobile <<<
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x1c
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000000  x2   0000000000000008  x3   0000000000000100
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x8   0000000000000000  x9   0000007e1b7f4020  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000000
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x12  0000000000000018  x13  0000000000000000  x14  0000000000000000  x15  000f2561f7049c9e
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x16  0000007e1b7f2520  x17  0000007e1b71b344  x18  00000000ffffffff  x19  0000000000000000
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x20  0000000000000000  x21  0000007e1d0d03c0  x22  0000007e1b3feaf0  x23  0000007e1d0d03f0
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x24  0000000000000001  x25  00000000ffffffff  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000000000008
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     x28  0000007e1b7c4798  x29  0000007e1b3feac0  x30  0000007e1b722bac
05-23 09:23:18.815 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     sp   0000007e1b3feab0  pc   0000007e1b71b358  pstate 0000000060000000
05-23 09:23:18.823 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
05-23 09:23:18.823 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0000000000068358  /data/app/com.picmix.mobile-2/base.apk (offset 0x215e000)
05-23 09:23:18.823 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 000000000006fba8  /data/app/com.picmix.mobile-2/base.apk (offset 0x215e000)
05-23 09:23:18.824 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0000000000063bbc  /data/app/com.picmix.mobile-2/base.apk (offset 0x215e000)
05-23 09:23:18.824 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000000000068258  /system/lib64/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+196)
05-23 09:23:18.824 21603-21603/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 000000000001dc00  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+16)`

Answer (score 1):

libRSSupportIO.so is an optional component, you can ignore the messages about it.

I believe the real cause is not able to find librs.img2alloc.so. Can you double check that if librs.img2alloc.so is on your device?

Comment: It's in the APK I built, that's for sure. In the armeabi-v7a, x86, and arm64-v8a parts of the lib folder.